# How to convert between the logit function and the sigmoid?

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

So I just learnt that the two are inverses of each other. This might be a completely stupid question... but what's the calculation to convert this:
$$\log \frac {x} {(1-x)}$$
into this:
$$\frac {1} {1+e^{-x}}$$
and while we're at it, the last equation into this:
$$\frac {e^x} {e^x+1}$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from
$$
y = \log \frac {x} {(1-x)}
$$
solve for $x$.
First exponentiate both sides
$$
e^y = \frac {x} {(1-x)}
$$
Invert
$$
\frac{1}{e^{y}} = \frac{1-x}{x}
\\
e^{-y} = \frac{1}{x}-1
$$
Add $1$
$$
1+e^{-y} = \frac{1}{x}
$$
and invert
$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-y}} = x
$$

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!